# Optimising a Query with 1 million rows

Tags: mysql, optimization, query-optimization

I've been trying to optimise this query I've got, originally I was using INNER JOIN for the vip.tvip database however noticed that people that didn't exist in that table weren't showing and read I have to use a LEFT JOIN which has caused further issues.

```
SELECT sb_admins.srv_group AS role, rankme.lastconnect, rankme.steam, rankme.name, rankme.pfp, vip.tvip.vip_level FROM bans.sb_admins
INNER JOIN rankme ON CONCAT("STEAM_0:", rankme.authid) = sb_admins.authid
LEFT JOIN vip.tvip ON tvip.playerid = rankme.authid
AND gid > 0 ORDER BY rankme.name;
```

This is the query I'm currently using, it seems to take around 5 seconds to get the result due to the rankme table being 1.3 million rows. I am also attaching the EXPLAIN for this query too, I'm not that well versed in MySQL queries so apologies if I am butchering this.

[image: EXPLAIN Query]

If someone could give an in-sight on how to fix this, would be tremendously helpful. I have created keys for anything which I could such as name being a FULLTEXT key etc but still no prevail.

Cheers.

Comment: I can see that one of your join conditions is using `CONCAT`.  This will render that join non _sargable_, meaning that MySQL will not be able to use any index to optimize that particular join.  Consider fixing your data model such that you can join directly on columns, without needing to use `CONCAT`.

Comment: Thanks Tim - didn't know that. Unfortunately, with the way Steam renders their Steam ID's the CS:GO engine uses the new universe whereas old software uses the old one hence the STEAM_1 and STEAM_0 issues.

Comment: Which of the tables does `gid` belong to? How much does `gid > 0` narrow your result? I.e. what percentage of rows are returned by this query? 99%? 1%? Less? How are the tables related? Is the `authid` unique in one or more of the tables? It seems strange that you join all three tables on the same ID. You may thus be producing an undesired cartesian product.

Comment: sb_admins.gid is where it originates from, it's basically the group ID for staff members. Only about 10-20 will have it.

Comment: What table is `gid` in???  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: You need something like `WHERE tvip IS NULL` to find the missing people.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try:

```
SELECT sb_admins.srv_group AS role, rankme.lastconnect, rankme.steam, rankme.name, rankme.pfp, vip.tvip.vip_level FROM bans.sb_admins
INNER JOIN rankme ON rankme.authid = REPLACE(sb_admins.authid,"STEAM_0:","")
LEFT JOIN vip.tvip ON tvip.playerid = rankme.authid
AND gid > 0 ORDER BY rankme.name;
```

This should be able to use the index on `rankme.authid` in rankme. (if that exists...)

Comment: What was the speed? The 'other' one was about 5 seconds, and this one?  (just curious) 

Comment: Not even a second 